# Parsing subset of markdown with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

To display comments on my blog, I want to parse just a subset of markdown. Namely, links, inline code, code blocks and paragraphs.

I'm having a hard time with fenced code blocks because the regex collide with both the one for inline code and paragraphs.

Here is my function:

````
function parseMd(text) {
    const codeblock = /```([^]+?.*?[^]+?[^]+?)```/g
    const code = /`(.*?)`/g
    const link = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g
    const paragraph = /(.+((\r?\n.+)*))/g

    return text.replace(codeblock, '<pre><code>$1</code></pre>')
    .replace(code, '<code>$1</code>')
    .replace(link, '<a href="$2">$1</a>')
    .replace(paragraph, '<p>$1</p>');
}
````

Ideally, I'd need `code` and `paragraph` regexes to ignore eveyrhing that matches `codeblock`, but as it's a multi-line one, it's getting tricky!

Comment: Seemed the most efficient way, but I'm openned to any suggestion. I just don't want to include a lib just for that!

Comment: Sounds interesting. How would you approach that?

Comment: Using Regex to _parse_ text or html is a really bad idea. That is what _parsers_ are for. Here is one idea: https://codepen.io/kvendrik/pen/Gmefv

Comment: @Amessihel awesome, thank you!

Comment: @LGSon the link you pointed me to is about using regex too… But yeah, [I am aware](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) it is not the greatest idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation provided below relies on **`innerHTML`** attribute **inspection** and **editing**.

It follows these major steps:

1. Parse **code blocks first** to **protect** them from further substitutions;
2. **Inject** the result in an HTML element as an `innerHTML` attribute to let the **browser** **parse** and turn it **into a `Node` set** (now code blocks are protected);
3. Replace the **remaining text** (which are now text nodes) by **`<P>`** elements to get your **paragraphs** parsed, and perform **inline elements parsing** inside to finally get **[links](http://stackoverflow)** and **`inline code`**.

Below a tested snippet.

````js
// Some HTML elements used througout the parsing

var resultDiv = document.getElementById("rendered-result")
var resultSrcTA = document.getElementById("resultsrc");

// convert() - Our lite MD parser

function convert() {
  var mdt = document.getElementById("md").value;
  // First we parse the blocks to prevent them to be parsed later on
  parseCodeBlocks(mdt);
  // Then we deal with the remaning text, which are paragraphs
  parseParagraphs();
  resultSrcTA.value = resultDiv.innerHTML;
}

// This function simply performs a regexp substitution on a given text
// and inject it into the result HTML element (resultDiv)
// as an inner HTML string to let the browser parting it

function parseCodeBlocks(text) {
  const codeblock = /```\s*([^]+?.*?[^]+?[^]+?)```/g;
  resultDiv.innerHTML = 
    text.replace(codeblock, '<pre><code>$1</code></pre>');
}

// This function replaces remaining text nodes with paragraphs
// (The tricky part)

function parseParagraphs() {
  var nodes = resultDiv.childNodes;
  // Looping through the nodes
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    // If the current node isn't a text node, next!
    if (nodes[i].nodeType != 3) continue;
    // Converting the current text node as an array of <P> elements
    ps = createPElementFromMDParagraphs(nodes[i].nodeValue);
    
    
    // Reverse looping through the <P> elements
    // Since we insert them right after the parsed text node
    for (var j = ps.length -1 ; j > -1 ; j--) {
      resultDiv.insertBefore(ps[j], nodes[i].nextSibling)
    }
    // We've done with paragraph insertion, time to remove
    // the parsed text node
    resultDiv.removeChild(nodes[i]);
    // Updating i : we added n paragraph and removed one text node
    i += ps.length - 1;
  }
}

// This function return for a given text a <P> array representing
// the content

function createPElementFromMDParagraphs(text) {
  const paragraph = /(.+)((\r?\n.+)*)/g;
  const code = /`(.*?)`/g;
  const link = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g;
  var ps = [];
  var matches;
  
  // We loop through paragraph regex matches
  // For each match, we create a <P> element and we push it
  // into the result array
  while ((matches = paragraph.exec(text)) !== null) {

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[1]));
    
    // And we have here an opportunity to format the inline elements
    // Note that links will be parsed inside a code element and will work
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(code, '<code>$1</code>');
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(link, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');

    ps.push(p);
  }

  return ps;
}
````

```css
/* Just to get it fancy */

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15ex;
}

div#rendered-result {
  min-height:10ex;
  height:10ex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:1em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

div#rendered-result > pre {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 1em;
  padding:0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

div#rendered-result > pre > code {
  margin: 0;
}

/* To check if this is a well parsed paragraph. */

div#rendered-result > p::first-letter {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:darkred;
}
```

````html
<p>Type your markdown text below:</p>
<textarea id="md">
The first paragraph.

```
A code block very well catched
Haha this `inline code` wont be parsed.
```

And a sentence with [two](http://stackoverflow.com) [links](http://askbuntu.com).

And another with an `inline code` and a [link](http://superuser.com).

```
And another code block
```

And another with an link as `[inline code](http://superuser.com)`.

Last sentence.
</textarea>
<p>
  <!-- yes it's bad -->
  <button onclick="convert()">Convert it</button>
</p>
<p>Result</p>
<div id="rendered-result">
</div>
<p>Source:</p>
<textarea id="resultsrc">
</textarea>
````

Comment: Awesome! Although my ƒn [ended working](https://jsfiddle.net/d28c39fn/) (yet with an empty `p` tag before the code blocks) you approach is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage the regexes in the [markedjs](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) project.

Comment: Whoops, looks like the marked project does not use regexes anymore